# Directory 'static' gives 404 error

Tags: apache, xampp

On a Windows machine running XAMPP I have a folder in my web root called 'static'. It and everything in it return a 404 error even though the folder is there.

[image: static directory]

If I change the name of the folder, e.g. 'statics', all is well. I have other servers (Ubuntu) running Apache and I do not have this problem.

The site is a copy of one of the sites on one of our Linux servers. What can I do or change to allow the directory to work as named?

**EDIT** vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin jablanchard@foo.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/home/app/gateway"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias 127.0.0.*
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/home/app/gateway/>
    # allow .htaccess overrides to work
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex login.html index.html index.php
</Directory>

# this matches a link to any project directory to the physical webui directory
AliasMatch ^/projects/([-\w]*)/(.*)$ /home/src/gateway/webui/$2
<Directory /home/src/gateway/webui>
    DirectoryIndex home.html
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: what is the full path of the folder? the static

Comment: No special handling for /static in your apache configuration?

Comment: Can you show us your vhosts?

Comment: I have added the vhosts file @Sculper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting ready to re-install XAMPP but made one last pass through the config files for Apache. I found the problem was this bit of code in the httpd.conf file -

```
Alias "/static" "C:/xampp/htdocs/static"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/static">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am not sure if this is part of the XAMPP install as all of the edits I have made to this installation are in the vhosts file. Once commented out the static directory, as I have defined it, works properly now.